# How to add 3rd party libraries to unity android build using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, unity-game-engine

I have this Unity 5.4 project, and I build it separately for iOS and Android.
On the iOS side, life is rather easy. Unity generates an XCode project which I then use `cocoapods` to add 3rd party libraries to.

On the Android side, the Android Project that Unity "builds" (exports), is not a standard Android Studio project, and you need to import it, instead of just opening it.
This leads to some complications, beyond my grasp of how Android studio works.
I believe it all boils down to getting Gradle to include the 3rd party libraries into the build, but since the app does not start the regular way, things don't end up running.
Has anyone added 3rd party libraries to a Unity/Android Studio project? any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file?

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 , Unity does not generate a `build.gradle` file, and Android Studio while  importing asks if you want to move to Gradle but doesn't actually do anything about it.

Comment: Hmm. Never used Unity, but if you want to add libraries, then you'll likely need a Gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

If the third party libraries are in aar/jar format, there is an option in the "inspector" tab to include them when Unity builds.

Usually you will be able to find .aar / .jar versions of the library you want on [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) or [Maven](http://search.maven.org/).

Another way is to see if the source code is hosted on Github, and build it into an .aar/.jar yourself in Android Studio